# Rendering Complicated Models in Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, web, three.js, 3d

if some rockstar could look through my code real quick and tell me why I cant render/see my three.js model I'd be forever in your debt!
I'll post the whole script, but I think some preliminary info is important.  Basically, I have thousands of points that look like this:

```
472232.14363148 2943288.56768013 200.129142"
472237.03086105 2943289.62356560 200.119496"
472241.91809061 2943290.67945108 200.109851"
472246.80532018 2943291.73533656 200.100205"
...and so on...
```

and a bunch of faces that look like this:

```
["1021 1020 1061", "640 754 641", "1534 1633 1535", "4701 27 26", "654 753 655", ...and so on...
```

When I extracted all the data and configured it correctly I then push it to the geometry and try to add it to the scene but with no success.  Here's the whole script:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 50, 50 );
    camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color : 0x00cc00 } );

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    var points = bigData['LandXML']['Surfaces']['Surface']['Definition']['Pnts']['P']
    var faces = bigData['LandXML']['Surfaces']['Surface']['Definition']['Faces']['F']

  for(i=0;i<points.length;i++){
        var [point1,point2,point3] = points[i]['__text'].split(' ').map(Number)
        //point1 *= .00001
        //point2 *= .00001
        //point3 *= .00001
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(point1,point2,point3))
    }

  for(i=0;i<faces.length;i++){
    console.log(faces[i]);
    var [face1,face2,face3] = faces[i].split(' ').map(Number)
    var face = new THREE.Face3(face1 - 1,face2 - 1, face3 - 1)
    geometry.faces.push(face)
  }

  scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ) );
```

You can see that in the for loop for the points, I have multiplied them by .00001 to scale the model because otherwise the numbers are so huge, if that makes sense. And I subtract 1 from each face because the data was not zero indexed.  Anyways, if any coding superhero took the time to read this and has some insight, please help me out! Thanks!

Comment: After assembling your geometry, tell it to build its bounding box (`geometry.computeBoundingBox();`). Then, check the values of the corners and center of the box (`geometry.boundingBox`) to ensure your camera is even _looking_ at the right place. This does _not_ guarantee that your camera's near/far will capture what is inside that box.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks for the input, I appreciate it and will try this out.  Heres the project if you'd like to try it yourself.  Again, I really appreciate your help so far.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=68384489612738199144

Comment: Where is the light ?

Comment: @soju I wasn't aware that I needed one, do you think that would help? I've never had to use a light with three.js before...

Comment: And where do you render your scene ?

Comment: @soju I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean.  All my configurations are in the script

Comment: @soju heres the project in github if you'd like to take a look
https://github.com/charlespettis/xml2threejs

Comment: @TheJim01 heres the github for my project in case you wanted to take a peek? I realized that the last link i sent was kind of sketchy looking
https://github.com/charlespettis/xml2threejs

Comment: I mean `renderer.render( scene, camera );`... Please read this https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene

Comment: @soju Yes, I hav initialized a renderer.  Still no model :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found your model on scene, the code missed those parts:

1. Your model has big coordinates, but small dimension. After dividing
   all coordinates by 100.000 it has `boundingSphere` center at (4.72;
   29,432;  0,00192) and `boundingSphere` radius 0,00480, So you need
   to either translate model so it has center at (0;0;0) or move camera
   target to it's center;
2. `geometry.computeFaceNormals()` must be called after building faces
   in order to make faces resposive to lighting and shading;
3. Scene needs some light in it. In curent state it will not show
   anything
4. Render loop or at least single call after adding mesh is required.

Here is fixed code, additionally I played with camera distance and added simple rotation animation. Also I used geometry translation approach to have an adequate rotation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DXF Test</title>
</head>
<body>


<script src="three.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JFM.js"></script>
<script>
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
    camera.position.set(0, 650, 650);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({color: 0x00cc00});

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    //geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(4.72227256402, 29.4328751179, 0.00200138787));
    //geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(3, 3, 0));
    //geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(5, 6, 0));

    //var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
    //scene.add( line );
    //renderer.render( scene, camera );

    var points = bigData['LandXML']['Surfaces']['Surface']['Definition']['Pnts']['P'];
    var faces = bigData['LandXML']['Surfaces']['Surface']['Definition']['Faces']['F'];

    console.log('Complete XML file');
    console.log(bigData);
    console.log('POINTS');
    console.log(points);
    console.log('FACES');
    console.log(faces);

    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var [point1, point2, point3] = points[i]['__text'].split(' ').map(Number);
        geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(point1, point2, point3));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
        var [face1, face2, face3] = faces[i].split(' ').map(Number);
        var face = new THREE.Face3(face1 - 1, face3 - 1, face2 - 1);
        geometry.faces.push(face)
    }

    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    // translate model so it's real center will be the same as mesh pivot
    geometry.translate(
        -geometry.boundingSphere.center.x,
        -geometry.boundingSphere.center.y,
        -geometry.boundingSphere.center.z
    );
    // compute bounding sphere again, because it was broken during translation
    geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    var sunLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    sunLight.position.set(200, 600, 1000);
    scene.add(sunLight);

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
        mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    }

    animate();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't like translation, you can remove it, remove rotation and after `computeBoundingSphere` do like this:

```
camera.position.set(
          geometry.boundingSphere.center.x + geometry.boundingSphere.radius,
          geometry.boundingSphere.center.y + geometry.boundingSphere.radius,
          geometry.boundingSphere.center.z + geometry.boundingSphere.radius,
  );
  camera.lookAt(
          geometry.boundingSphere.center.x,
          geometry.boundingSphere.center.y,
          geometry.boundingSphere.center.z,
  );
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Heres a better one I didnt realize before uploading the last one how weird the code was, here is the project so you can reproduce it yourself,  thanks so much : 
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=68384489612738199144

Comment: Here man, I put it on github in case you thought the last link was sketchy.  Thanks again.
https://github.com/charlespettis/xml2threejs

Comment: @CharlesPettis I found the solution, please read the updated answer

Comment: I will try this first thing tomorrow, but if you tried it and it works,  then THANK YOU!!! I have been racking my brain over this so you are the man.  Need anything, just message me.